# Read request header on load of React application

Tags: reactjs

When I open my React appliation link in browser SSO gets enabled and it adds the userid as part of the redirect request header to my react app. I know how to read the userid in a Java based app. But how do I get this value in React application? I have searched google and this forum as well but could not find any suitable solution. Is there a way to retrieve the value from request header on load?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned Java I will assume you are now using NodeJS in tandem with React.

If you wanted to get headers for example and you are using express.

```
app.get("/my_rest", (req, res) => {

 ...
   console.log(req.headers.referer)

 ...
});
```

Furthermore to see the entire header object you can do `console.log(req.headers)`

Comment: My backend is in Java Spring boot and UI in REACT